# MFC - CPropertyPageEx and scaling (4K monitor)

Tags: mfc, scaling

I'm upgrading an old MFC app to support 4K monitors. According to what information I can find, `CPropertySheetEx` 'implements Wizard97 style functionality'. It's a dialog with Previous and Next buttons and a banner.

Now MFC has done a poor job of scaling this dialog and I'm not sure what control I have over it.

4K is usually 200% scaling. The banner height is unchanged at 59 pixels (so is too small on a 4K monitor). The rest of the dialog seems to have scaled to about 150% (width, height).

I've tried `SetWindowPos` on the banner. This doesn't resize it and causes other dialog issues.

There's this note in the code, which makes me think the banner is dynamically constructed with the property sheet.

> ```
> // If the page has a header, we need to paint the area above the border.
> // By inspection (Spy++), the border is a static control with ID 0x3027
>      CWnd* pTopBorder = GetDlgItem(0x3027);
> ```

Any suggestions or guides would be appreciated.

- The app is DPI aware. Many MFC components scale properly (some need some work)
- Question - How can I get `CPropertyPageEX` dialogs to support scaling?
- Here's an image ![Scaling Issue]https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEJM5.jpg

Edit - 
The icon and the text in the banner can be resized and repositioned, only the height of the banner seems stuck at 50 pixels.

1. `CPropertyPageEx` is defined as `CPropertyPage` in MFC 11. It's derived directly from `CWnd`.
2. Having a look at the sources for `CPropertyPage` (atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgprop.cpp) there's no constructor where it creates buttons or banners (so I may be looking in the wrong place).
3. A PropertySheet seems to consist of

   - a graphic (user supplied),
   - a horizontal bar (static control),
   - a dialog resource from the Property Page currently displayed
   - another horizontal bar
   - a series of buttons (Prev , Next etc)
4. Have a look at my high def screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlpBA.jpg

   - The dialog and controls have rescaled
   - The vertical position of the horizontal bar and the property page are both unchanged from the unscaled version, leading to the ugly overlap you can see.

.

Comment: Have you tried the manifest tool and setting `High DPI Aware`?

Comment: There is no question mark in your question. What are you asking for?

Comment: Could you post a screen shot?

Comment: It's not a problem with `CPropertySheet`. You have added a static control on top of the property sheet, just below the title bar, that's not properly resized for DPI 200%. Look in `CMyPropertySheet::OnSize` (or whatever your class is called) and show what it's doing, as well as `CMyPropertySheet::OnInitDialog`